# HTML input EventListener - deselect

Tags: javascript, html

I have an event-listener on an HTML input that detects when you are activating the input with addEventListener('click').

I then want to add an event-listener that detects when the input element is no longer active. I used addEventListener('change') for this, but that obviously only works if the value in the input is changed.

Is there any smart way to do this? Here´s the current code:

```
document.querySelector("#" + key).addEventListener('click', fromTsep)
document.querySelector("#" + key).addEventListener('change', toTsep)
```

Comment: `blur` event ??

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! :)

Comment: Don't use `click` to determine if the input is active - use `focus` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focus for more detail).  If the user tabs into the input the `click` handler won't fire but `focus` will